# Jquery Mobile showing double form labels after form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, mobile

This is my first time using jquery mobile... I have form items like this -

```
<label for="five_miles">5 Miles</label>
<input type="radio" name="distlim" value="5" id="five_miles">
```

As it says in the documentation, to label form elements, you must use a label tag and the for should = the id of that form item.

And it works fine. I load the page, the form elements are being generated and look good.

But after I submit the form back to the same page, it shows the form with the generated button elements with the label text inside the element but also it shows the text for the label above each form element again.

The code generated by jquery looks like this -

```
<div class="ui-radio">
   <label for="yes" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-radio-on ui-btn-inherit ui-btn-icon-left">Yes</label>
   <input type="radio" name="transportation" class="transyes" id="yes" value="Yes" checked="">
 </div>
 <label for="yes">Yes</label>
```

I am thinking that maybe the dom is being loaded and the the jquery is loading afterwords and adding the other label element. Only happens after the form submit.

Tried putting my jscript files in the footer and in the header, and I tried putting the label above and below the form elements. ...not sure what else to do.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I overlooked in the docs that you have to wrap radio buttons and checkboxes with

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup"></fieldset>
```